# Order by entry in separate table in Webmatrix

Tags: sql, razor, webmatrix

I'm trying to do something in my new Webmatrix site, and I'm not sure it is possible.

I have the following 2 tables in my database.

**Property**
PropertyID,
PropertyName,
Primary_Image

**Images**
PropertyID,
ImageURL,
ImageID

I have set up a page for each property, which shows ALL images that belong to that property. The problem is, I want to order those images, so that the primary image shows at the top? How can I make that happen?

Here's  my current SQL query:

```
var images = db.query("SELECT * FROM Images JOIN Property ON Images.ImageID=Property.Primary_Image WHERE PropertyID = @0"), PropertyID;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

```
var images = db.query(@"SELECT t1.* FROM Images t1 LEFT JOIN Property t2 ON
    t1.ImageID = t2.Primary_Image WHERE t1.PropertyID = @0 ORDER BY
    t2.Primary_Image DESC", PropertyID);
```

With this query you filter the records from `Images` that have a given `PropertyID` joining with the matching rows of `Property`.
Since only the primary image has a matching row in `Property`, this record is the only that has a value in `Primary_Image`: ordering in descending order puts this record at the first place.

Comment: sorry for the delay, but managed to try this, and it's worked perfectly. Thanks for your help.